# How to install mock server and pact files for API testing?

Tags: javascript, web-api-testing

I'm new to API testing. I read few documents and tutorials about this topic. However I am not able to understand how to use & install the mock server and create the files to test the APIs. Can anyone help me with this? Moreover can anyone suggest me which tools are better to test a full roundtrip (backend & frontend) for APIs?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), which is a Google Chrome extension that is very popular for API testing.

It can simulate request calls, which you can craft data as you desired. i.e. data, header, and url.